# UWP live sound streaming project

Tags: audio, uwp, live

I am trying to create a live communication project between two machines only with sound based on the windows sample. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication . I am doing it in VB. What happens in the sample is that there is a mainpage and the user calls the scenario he wants to execute but in the main page (in a class called SampleConfiguration) is declared the MediaExtensionManager (line22) after that there is a void called EnsureMediaExtensionManager that registers scheme with the custom "stsp:" format. **This is what I cannot do**. So far I ve translated the sample succesfully and I can stream sound from my raspberry (I can hear it using the original sample written in C modified it only for sound) but I cannot register the StspSchemeHandler to work with my MediaElement and i always get a debug error MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D36C3 on the MediaFailed event of my MediaElement. If someone looks at the code of the sample lets say on Scenario2_VideoChat in line 42  EnsureMediaExtensionManager() is called.

```cs
public void EnsureMediaExtensionManager()
{
     if (mediaExtensionMgr == null)
     {
         mediaExtensionMgr = new Windows.Media.MediaExtensionManager();
         mediaExtensionMgr.RegisterSchemeHandler("Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspSchemeHandler", "stsp:");
     }
 }
```

But As far as I can understant this is called before everything else .. how can i call the same but using only one page ... MainPage thanks a lot

Comment: it seems that the reference "Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspSchemeHandler" in the registerSchemeHandler doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

> how can i call the same but using only one page ... MainPage

I'm not sure why you say *cannot do*, but for this question, instead of calling the method in another page, you could just put the method implementation inside the `MainPage`. To ensure it is called before others, it should be put inside constructor method may be like follows:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page
    Private mediaExtensionMgr As Windows.Media.MediaExtensionManager
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        If (mediaExtensionMgr Is Nothing) Then
            mediaExtensionMgr = New Windows.Media.MediaExtensionManager()
            mediaExtensionMgr.RegisterSchemeHandler("Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspSchemeHandler", "stsp:")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it... After a painfull searching afternoon!
1) right click Package.appxmanifest  -> view code
2)add this lines

```
    <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspSchemeHandler" ThreadingModel="both"/>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

And then it works no matter where you call it...